# A numpy.where error?

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy.where to find the indices of some values. However, numpy.where yields the wrong indices as you can see below. Can somebody else explain me why I am getting such wrong indices please?

Thanks.

```
In [1]: d = np.random.rand(3,4)

In [2]: d
Out[2]: 
array([[ 0.11694612,  0.95137658,  0.70099781,  0.06730629],
       [ 0.59989836,  0.52586768,  0.45387929,  0.76093495],
       [ 0.036541  ,  0.91714289,  0.2246452 ,  0.40785078]])

In [3]: np.where(d>0.9)
Out[3]: (array([0, 2]), array([1, 1]))
```

However,

```
In [4]: d[0,2]
Out[4]: 0.70099781000000005
In[5]: d[1,1]
Out[5]: 0.52586767999999995
```

Comment: You should check `d[0,1]` and `d[2,1]` instead. the first element of the tuple is row index, and the second is col index.

Comment: @ajcr Ah, sorry, wasn't aware this was a dupe.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: no problem - your answer here explains the function very well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `np.where` returns a tuple of arrays with the indices *in a given axis* of where your condition holds. So, perhaps this makes it clearer:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d = np.array([[ 0.11694612,  0.95137658,  0.70099781,  0.06730629],
...        [ 0.59989836,  0.52586768,  0.45387929,  0.76093495],
...        [ 0.036541  ,  0.91714289,  0.2246452 ,  0.40785078]])
>>> x, y = np.where(d > 0.9)
>>> d[x[0],y[0]]
0.95137658000000003
>>> d[x[1],y[1]]
0.91714289000000004
```

Note, this works well with the way `numpy` indexing works:

```
>>> d[x,y]
array([ 0.95137658,  0.91714289])
```

Note, this works with any dimensions:

```
>>> d.reshape(3,2,2)
array([[[ 0.11694612,  0.95137658],
        [ 0.70099781,  0.06730629]],

       [[ 0.59989836,  0.52586768],
        [ 0.45387929,  0.76093495]],

       [[ 0.036541  ,  0.91714289],
        [ 0.2246452 ,  0.40785078]]])
>>> d = d.reshape(3,2,2)
>>> x, y, z = np.where(d > 0.9)
>>> x
array([0, 2])
>>> y
array([0, 0])
>>> z
array([1, 1])
>>> d[x,y,z]
array([ 0.95137658,  0.91714289])
```

Comment: @hurrdrought well, this is `numpy`, which is actually quite different than your typical python library, I would say, But it is pretty internally consistent.